# Removing Element within many XML files

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a folder with 40 xml files where I need to remove the `<column ..../>` element.

I want to do them all in one go. Here's an example of the files I need modified:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <!-- generated using CMHInc.NHibernate.hbm.cst -->
  <class name="CMHInc.Lodge.Business.Core.ProductType, CMHInc.Lodge.Business.Core" table="ProductType" lazy="false" schema="CMHPos">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid" unsaved-value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" >
      <column name="Id" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" not-null="true" unique="true" index="PK_ProductType"/>
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <version name="RowId" column="RowId" generated="always" type="Byte[]"
      unsaved-value="null" access="field.camelcase-underscore"/>
    <property name="Type" type="String" access="field.camelcase-underscore" >
      <column name="Type" length="20" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
```

I would like to remove every instance of

```
<column name="Type" length="20" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true"/>
```

Here's my PowerShell code:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem c:\xml\*.xml | % { 
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)
    $xml.catalog.book |
        where { $_.title -eq "property" } |
        foreach { $_.RemoveAttribute("column") }
    $xml.Save($_.FullName)
}
```

I'm having the following errors:

> Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\xml\ActivityChargeCalculation.hbm.xml' is denied."

I looked up the security settings of the files and folder, but I am logged in as admin and just created those files.

Suggestions?

Comment: Using Win7, and I also tried "Resolve-Path" before the fullname.

Comment: Okay, so running powershell as Administrator resolved the Exception calling save issue, but it doesn't seem like the files are being modified at all. They however get saved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample XML is incomplete and does not match your code. Also, you want to remove nodes, not attributes. Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\xml\*.xml | ForEach-Object {
  $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)

  $xml.SelectNodes("//property/column") | Where-Object {
    $_.name -eq "Type" -and
    $_.length -eq "20" -and
    $_."sql-type" -eq "varchar" -and
    $_."not-null" -eq "true"
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ParentNode.RemoveChildNode($_)
  }

  $xml.Save($_.FullName)
}
```

Note that you need to run the script with admin permissions if normal users don't have write permission to the files in `C:\xml`.

Comment: So, I'm running the powershell ise .exe as Administrator and am receiving Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Access to the path * is denied". Also, "users" have been granted full permission. I had this similar error before and running it as Admin had fixed it, but not this time.

Comment: "Access denied" when users have full control over the file sounds like someone (or something) holding an open handle to that file. You can verify that for instance with Systinternals' [`handle`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) utility.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I ended up using .NET to resolve the nodes removal. Removed upwards of 2000 <column ..> nodes in 58 files. Also, to be noted, SelectNodes("//*column").

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Ansgar was relevant for a specific node of specific name, length (and other properties). My research have enlightened me a bit more onto powershell and the notable would be SelectNodes("//*column"). I ended up doing an itteration using .Net as I am more familiar with it.