# Removing element in multiple XML files that contain specific attribute

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

First, I'd like to reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246243/removing-element-within-many-xml-files) as it is what I've based the powershell script off of with minor modifications.

The goal of the modified script (seen below) is to go through every XML in a folder and if it has an object within an object, where the source file ends with an .eps, then to remove the object and everything within. From the referenced link above, it looked as if I would have to ensure that all objects in the attribute is accounted for. I have tried to use wildcards and when I ran it, it didn't pop any errors, however, it also didn't remove the secondary object tag.

Here is a sample XML of the object/object:

```
<object class="graphic svg eps file_name:AR1.svg name:AR1" data="sample.svg"     height="100" type="image/svg+xml" width="100">
    <object class="graphic svg eps file_name:AR1.eps name:AR1" data="sample.eps" height="400" type="application/postscript" width="400">
        <p>NONE</p>
    </object>
</object>
```

Here is the modification:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\test\*.xml' | ForEach-Object {
  $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)

  $xml.SelectNodes("//object/object") | Where-Object {
    $_.class -eq "*" -and
    $_.data -eq "*.eps" -and
    $_.height -eq "*" -and
    $_.type -eq "application/postscript" -and
    $_.width -eq "*"
  } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ParentNode.RemoveChildNode($_)
  }

  $xml.Save($_.FullName)
}
```

I was under the impression that wildcards should still work, and because the attributes with wildcards are random based on the XML filename and image filename that using a wildcard would be best.

I'm very still very green and new to PowerShell but appreciate any help that can be given.

Edit:

With the help of @TheMadTechnician, I've updated the script to below which works!

```
    $items | ForEach-Object {
      $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)

      $xml.SelectNodes("//*[@type='application/postscript']") | %{ $_.parentnode.removechild($_) }

      $xml.Save($_.FullName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `Where` statement doesn't work. You can see this if you just run the first part of that command:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//object/object") | Where-Object {
  $_.class -eq "*" -and
  $_.data -eq "*.eps" -and
  $_.height -eq "*" -and
  $_.type -eq "application/postscript" -and
  $_.width -eq "*"
}
```

That returns nothing because only 1 of those evaluate to True, and that's the type which literally equals what you indicate

Wildcards are great, but you have to use them appropriately. The `-eq` operator is literal, and does not accept wildcards. So when you say `$_.class -eq "*"` that only returns `$true` when `$_.class` is a string containing only `*`. Where you *can* use wildcards like that is the `-like` operator.

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//object[contains(@data,'.eps') and @type='application/postscript']") | 
Where-Object {
    $_.data -like "*.eps" -and
    $_.type -eq "application/postscript"
  }|%{$_.parentnode.removechild($_)}
```

This could all be simplified with a better XPath query:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//object[contains(@data,'.eps') and @type='application/postscript']") | %{ $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
```